# ObjectMapper returrning NIL in Swift

Tags: json, swift, objectmapper

I'm trying to use Object mapper https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper to convert a JSON string into a Swift object. Note I've simplified the object to a single field here - obviously my real response has more fields!

My response is:

```
data arrray response [{
chat =     {
    "_id" = 1;
}}]
```

So I want to convert to my chat class:

```
public class Chat: Mappable {
var _id: String? }
public required init?(map: Map){     
}
public func mapping(map: Map) {
    _id <- map["_id"]
}
}
```

So I convert my data array to a dictionary

```
let jsonResponse = dataArray [0]
let discResponse = jsonResponse as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
```

I can even access my field manually

```
let chat = discResponse["chat"]
let id = chat!["_id"]
print ("CHAT ID", id)
```

But mapping to the object

```
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: chat, options: .prettyPrinted)

let user = Chat(JSONString: String( describing: jsonData))
```

returns nil

Why?

Comment: What is `jsonData`? And don't misuse the `String( describing` initializer. Consider that `_id` could be also an `Int`.

Comment: let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: chat, options: .prettyPrinted)

Comment: _id is an alphanumeric string

Comment: use Mapper<Chat>().map(JSONObject: chat)

Comment: @Luzo if you put your comment as an answer I can accept it, thank you I looked at the docs and didn't see JSONObject constructor (it's not there?) but this solves it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just putting my comment as an answer, if someone will stuck on the same issue: use `Mapper<Chat>().map(JSONObject: chat)`. It should help your cause.